# Create a Data Pump (Export/Import) History Table Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, datapump

Can you create a table in Oracle database which stores all the details about the data pump operations or keeps a history of all data pump transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I checked the Oracle documentation to double check and to the best of my knowledge I can confirm that such a facility is Not available. I referred this documentation that you can verify as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A

There is no such feature/ability provided as an in-built featute by Oracle as of Oracle 12c.

Thanks, 
DBuserN